# How to store max value of a Spark DataFrame column into a variable and increment it?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, max

I am trying to extract the max value of a column "ID" in Spark DataFrame and to increment whenever an insert is performed.

I am able to print the max value but am not able to store it in variable

```
max_id = df.agg({"ID":"max"}).collect()[0]
print max_id["max(ID)"]
```

`id2 = max_id["max{"ID"}]` throws error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How to extract the same into a variable and increment it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to extract the max value of a column as int.

maxid=int(df.describe("ID").filter("summary = 'max'").select("ID").collect()[0].asDict()['ID']

print maxid
---result :3

id2=maxid+1
print  id2
---result 4

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following dataframe:

```
l1 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6), (12,537)]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(l1,['ID','col2'])

max_id=df1.agg({"ID":"max"}).collect()[0]
```

The Variable max_id is a [pyspark.sql.types.Row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row). You can check that with type():

```
type(max_id)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
```

Elements of a pyspark.sql.types.Row can be accessed like dictionaries with squared brackets:

```
max_id['max(ID)']
```

So all you want to change is your max_id assignment:

```
max_id=df1.agg({"ID":"max"}).collect()[0]['max(ID)']
type(max_id)
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

max_id is now an int that can be incremented:

```
max_id = max_id+1
```

The problem with your code above is, that you have used curly brackets.

Comment: Hi Cronoik, thanks for your answer, i am now able to store max value in the variable max_id, when i print the increment one, i get the error

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: Please show me your print. Your are probably trying to do something like `print('bla' + max_id)`. That will not work as python does rarely implicit conversions. You have to convert it to a string when you want it printed with another string: `print('bla' + str(max_id))`.

Comment: max_id=DimDF.agg({"ID":"max"}).collect()[0]['max(ID)']
print max_id
//result : 3 ( max value in column)

max_id = max_id+1
print max_id
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

i'm just trying to print the int value

Comment: It dint work. is the output of max_id=DimDF.agg({"ID":"max"}).collect()[0]['max(ID)'] result in int ?                i'm not able to see the type of (max_id).  type is  in python. what's its equivalent in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = spark.range(5)
```

If you only need **one aggregation per column**, `.agg({'id':'max'})` is OK:

```py
max_id = df.agg({'id':'max'}).collect()[0][0]

print(max_id)
# 4
```

If you need **more aggregations per column**, `.agg({'id':'max', 'id':'min'}` wouldn't work (only the last one would be returned).

You would need `.select`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

max_min = df.select(F.max('id'), F.min('id')).collect()[0]
max_id, min_id = max_min[0], max_min[1]

print(max_id, min_id)
# 4 0
```